# SQL replace and calculate character length and replace again

Tags: sql, replace, firebird

I want to do an update on a Firebird table. So far not a problem:

```
update MYTABLE
set params = replace(params, 'SOMEHOST', 'SOMENEWHOST')
```

Before the update statement my params look like this:

```
s:91:"{"server":"SOMEHOST","port":"21","ssl":false,"user":"DUMMY","pwd":"SECRET","path":"FOLDER"}";
```

After my update the params look like this:

```
s:91:"{"server":"SOMENEWHOST","port":"21","ssl":false,"user":"DUMMY","pwd":"SECRET","path":"FOLDER"}";
```

So far it's ok.

But the frontend program can not handle this because there is a checksum in the params.

The value **s:91** is the character length from the opening brace to the closing one.

From row to row the character length can differ because there is another path, user or pwd.

Is it possible to calculate the character length from the opening brace to the closing and extend the update statement with Firebird?

Comment: Where is ' s:91' set? Is it another column in your table? Or is it calculated on runtime? However, calculating the length between { and } is not a problem - you can use charindex for this

Comment: This seems like you should be normalising your data, if I am honest.

Comment: The  's:91'  is set in the same column params. So it's a kind of prefix. It's an firebird database.

Comment: Firebird or SQL Server ?, because you have tagged it as SQL Server, but said Firebird on a comment

Comment: Do it in the frontend, or in whatever part of your app understands the pickled/frozen/serialized JSON you store in the `"params"` field.  You _can_ force something to work, but it will never be safe for all possible values unless your logic understands the encoding.  (What if SOMEHOST appears as part of the "user" or "pwd" or "path" values, for example?)  This is similar to editing CSV files with `sed` — it works just fine, until it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first replace the old host by the new host, and then do a second replace to set the new size prefix.

Use the `position` function to locate the "{" and "}" positions and build the "s:91:" and "s:94:" strings, to replace them.

```
update MYTABLE set 
       PARAMS = replace(replace(PARAMS, 'SOMEHOST', 'SOMENEWHOST'), 
                       's:' || cast(position('}' in PARAMS) - position('{' in PARAMS) + 1 as varchar(16)) || ':',
                       's:' || cast(position('}' in replace(PARAMS, 'SOMEHOST', 'SOMENEWHOST')) - position('{' in PARAMS) + 1 as varchar(16)) || ':')
```

PS: It would be much safer if when replacing the Host you also include the identifier. So if by any chance that Host name is casually a subpart of the password or folder they won't be changed, corrupting those values.

> replace(PARAMS, '"server":"SOMEHOST"', '"server":"SOMENEWHOST"')

instead of

> replace(PARAMS, 'SOMEHOST', 'SOMENEWHOST')

That makes this result query :

```
update MYTABLE set 
       PARAMS = replace(replace(PARAMS, '"server":"SOMEHOST"', '"server":"SOMENEWHOST"'), 
                       's:' || cast(position('}' in PARAMS) - position('{' in PARAMS) + 1 as varchar(16)) || ':',
                       's:' || cast(position('}' in replace(PARAMS, '"server":"SOMEHOST"', '"server":"SOMENEWHOST"')) - position('{' in PARAMS) + 1 as varchar(16)) || ':')
```

Comment: Firebirds respects the SQL standard and thus uses `||` for string concatenation, not `+` (which is to add numbers in SQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, I forgot it. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @hellskitchen You are welcome. Please read the PS I have added, it would make your query much safer.